# How do I get bank information using ifsc code or swift code..?

Tags: php, bank

I have only IFSC/swift code using that IFSC/swift code I want to get bank information like bank name, branch , address...etc

Anyone have idea first it is possible to get bank information from only IFSC/swift code. If yes possible than that type of process what should I do..?

Should I contact to bank or is their any other api or other provider who will provide information which is correct.

Any idea please let me know..?

Comment: Here is the link which found my self https://market.mashape.com/nviror/bank-ifsc-and-micr-india#ifsc but it'll working for only ifsc code.

Answer (score 2):

The Search By IFSC Code method of [Bank IFSC Code API](https://github.com/kaustubhk24/Indian-Banks-Data/wiki/V1-Documentation#1--api-to-get-bank-details-using-ifsc) might help you. Bank Swift IFSC Code is a service that allows users to get any Indian bank's Branch IFSC Code and details. The database includes more than 150 banks and one million branches. The Bank Swift IFSC Code API enables developers to programmatically access their database of IFSC codes, Swift codes, Micr codes, branch codes, and other details for free. A PHP implementation of the API is available.

Comment: I have check site where I have found on this url http://www.bankswiftifsccode.com/swift-bic-codes-api.php they said To activate your key send your requests to howtoreahu@gmail.com but emai sending is failed any idea..?

Comment: Guys the link that you have provided is broken

Answer (score 1):

You can use mashape for Search by IFSC code API: https://market.mashape.com/navii/bank-ifsc-and-micr-india#ifsc

edit: [url updated]

Comment: It is only for ifsc but I want it for both using swift code and IFSC code. do you have any idea for swift code..?

Answer (score 1):

Officially there is no such API for SWIFT, IFSC and MICR code.

You can find it from RBI web site.

If you want banks details such as bank name, branch, address and contact details for all banks try these links:

Everything is available here

https://github.com/kaustubhk24/Indian-Banks-Data/wiki/V1-Documentation#1--api-to-get-bank-details-using-ifsc

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there are no such RESTFUL OFFICIAL API . However you can get an updated list of BANK IFSC Code and branch details from RBI Website .

Also why not build an api yourself? Just download the list, (it is updated periodically on RBI Website ) import into a db table and host it. 
Avail an api endpoint to get the data from your own webservice. :)

Edit:

I also found this github repo , try that 
https://github.com/mangrep/ifsc-rest-api

Comment: I have check that api and it give me the bank information that is good but I also want bank info using swift code is it possible..? any idea for about it..?

Answer (score 0):

IFSC code is more than to find information about bank and its details. There are many option to find but simple and effective way is through official website of represent bank branch locator. Or you can [find bank by ifsc code](http://indianbankdetails.com/ifsc-code.php) by entering 11 character IFSC code on that box.

Answer (score 0):

Yes correct there not such official api for either swift or IFSC code.

However i found one website which gives information about both swift and ifsc codes both and found it to be updated very frequently.

> Find Bank info by swift code :
>   http://swiftifsccode.com/bank-from-swift
>  Find Bank info by IFSC
>   code : http://swiftifsccode.com/bank-from-ifsc
>  Find Bank info by
>   NEFT code : http://swiftifsccode.com/bank-from-neft-code
>  Find IFSC
>   codes by bank and branches : http://swiftifsccode.com/
>  Find Swift
>   codes by bank and branches : http://swiftifsccode.com/swift

And other similar links are also given.

Answer (score 0):

I know one REST API which supports search via IFSC or MICR code. Although it has a restriction of 100 hits a day. But I guess that is enough for small to medium websites.

Check here: http://www.firstatom.org/apis/ifsc