# Is there anyway to get BIC/SWIFT Code full details

Tags: banking

Is there anyway to get a complete feed of full BIC (Business Identifier Codes issued by SWIFT) codes. This is the 11 digit version (bank code [4 letters], country code [2 letters], location code [2 digits], Branch code [3 digits]).

Comment: And what's your problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get bank information using ifsc code or swift code..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38651144/how-do-i-get-bank-information-using-ifsc-code-or-swift-code)

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to have a subscription to SWIFT's [BIC Plus](https://swiftref.swift.com/bic-plus) data service. This is a pay for service. They provide the data in text (tab delimited) and XML format.